# How to force elements in SWT to display in English?

Tags: java, localization, swt

I am Brazilian and I am developing an application that uses SWT. But I need the elements in the SWT to always appear to the user in English. At the moment they appearing in Portuguese for me because my OS is in Portuguese. So would it be possible to force all the elements to  remain in English regardless of the OS?

Comment: welcome to the site. i corrected the grammar a little but do not let that stop you from contributing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most SWT `Widget`s are OS dependent, meaning they use native OS elements. This is the case for all non-emulated widgets. You won't be able to change the language on these (i.e. choose a different one than the selected OS language).

For emulated widgets, [this](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/language.php) link explains how to force a certain language.

Answer (score 0):

Normally it is advisable to support [Internationalization and localization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization) in ones application. Have a look at `java.util.ResourceBundle` and its supporting classes.

For example, the default language on my OS is English but using the `java.util.ResourceBundle` APIs, I can target Portuguese or any other customer.

### Code

#### Message Class

```
package com.sample;
import java.util.MissingResourceException;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class Messages {
    private static final String BUNDLE_NAME = "com.sample.messages"; //$NON-NLS-1$
    private static final ResourceBundle RESOURCE_BUNDLE = ResourceBundle
            .getBundle(BUNDLE_NAME);
    private Messages() {
    }
    public static String getString(String key) {
        try {
            return RESOURCE_BUNDLE.getString(key);
        } catch (MissingResourceException e) {
            return '!' + key + '!';
        }
    }
}
```

#### Test Class

```
package com.sample;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Display display = new Display();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display, SWT.CLOSE);
        shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));
        shell.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false));
        shell.setText(Messages.getString("Test.TITLE")); //$NON-NLS-1$
        Button button = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
        button.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false));
        button.setText(Messages.getString("Test.GREETINGS")); //$NON-NLS-1$

        shell.pack();
        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch())
                display.sleep();
        }
        display.dispose();
    }
}
```

#### message.properties file

```
Test.GREETINGS=Olá Mundo \!\!
Test.TITLE=\u0644\u064A\u0644\u0629 \u0633\u0639\u064A\u062F\u0629
```

### Output

[image]

**Note-** The title is in arabic and the button text is in Portuguese.

Comment: +1 However, this won't change the language on, for example, SWT `FileDialog`.

Comment: @Baz - Well what you mentioned is mostly true in some sense, for example, it is possible to change the title of the file dialog using `fileDialog.setText(Messages.getString("Test.TITLE"));` but rest of the area will be controlled by the OS. In fact this is applicable for all the text input controls.

Comment: True, forgot about the title.

Comment: Downvoted - IMHO, it is fairly obvious the question is not about custom labels. Hence this answer is misleading.

Comment: @Eugene: Read the question again there is a lot of ambiguity `I need the elements in the SWT`!! What are the elements the author is talking about? If we consider element as the basic entity then in SWT it corresponds to widgets. Anyway, see my response to Baz's comment, where I have acknowledged that it is OS dependent.